# Is it good practice to pass angular services by constructor down to child?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have been passing service to child components or objects a few times calling constructor myself, but it always feels weird considering use of DI.

```
export class Component {
    constructor(private translateService: TranslateService, private http: HttpClient){}

    someFunction() {
        const item = new Item("name", this.translateService, this.http);
    }
}

export class Item {
   constructor(name: string, private translateService: TranslateService, private http: HttpClient){}
}
```

I feel I shouldn't really do that, I think dependency injection should take care of that. The services are being used in both Component and Item. Can this solution be improved somehow?

Comment: Why does Item (which sounds like a data object) need services? That's rather unusual.

Comment: Well, actually in real code the Item was kind of background task for displaying notifications, but the example would be much longer. The task needs translate service to get proper translations. I thought also about passing to the task already translated strings, but I don't see it as a better alternative.

Comment: Ok. Can the background task be created by the injector or is its lifecycle more dynamic than that?

Comment: I think it can be created by the injector